# Why this statement is evaluated to False even it is true?

Tags: python

I started learning python but I've noticed something unsual, something that I do not understand, why the expression provided below it's evaluated to false even it is true??

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,"Hi"]
"Hi" in l  # returns True
"Hi" in l == True # returns False
```

Answer (score 4):

`"Hi" in l == True` is evaluated as `("Hi" in l) and (l == True)` which is `False`.

Explanation from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z

Comment: Actually it’s evaluated as `'Hi' in (l == True)` which is `'Hi' in False`

Comment: @NChauhan If that were true, `'Hi' in l == True` would cause a type error, just like `'Hi' in (l == True)` and `'Hi' in False` do.

Comment: @sepp2k Ah my mistake.

Comment: It's pretty weird that `in` is considered to be the same kind of comparison operator as `<` and `==`. Is there any reasonable case where you would want to include it in a chain like this?

Comment: @Barmar IMHO there is no such case where I will use `in` comparison in a chain. Only simple and clear chains like `0 < x < 1` are commonly used. `in` in a chain  produces too much mustakes and confusion.

Comment: So you think it's not intentional, just a side effect of the prcedence rules?

Comment: I think yes, just a `status-by-design` thing.